# sftp to lineage

Tags: lineageos, photos, ftp

In lineage 17.1 I installed the app `SSH server` (by Banana Studio, from Play store).
When starting and accessing by my PC (smartphone and PC are in WiFi) via `sftp -P 2222 myuser@192.168.0.7` I see no files there, but there are photos in the smartphone folder `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera`.
When doing `cd storage` the connection is closed. My PC has ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Could you mention which "ssh server" app? I found multiple apps with the same name but different capitalization: [Ssh server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.sshserver) and [SSH Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.sshserver.tv).

Comment: @Andrew T. SSH Server by Banana Studio. (But I do not have to stick to this one.)

Comment: `cd storage` is not a valid command. You should do `cd /storage/emulated/0`. But that would work only if your SSH server app has Storage permission granted.

Comment: @Irfan Latif When I do `cd /storage/emulated/0` then it says "Connection closed" and exits. I cannot see whether SSH server app has the permissions.

Comment: Use OpenSSH on Termux: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access#OpenSSH

Comment: @Irfan Latif After installing termux, starting sftp and executing `get *` it says `remote readdir("/storage/emulated/0"): Permission denied`.

Comment: Grant Storage permission as already said.

Comment: OK, that works. I have not knewn how to. But it's just going to Settings -> Apps -> Termux -> Permissions) and granting (i e. checking the box).

Answer (score 0):

Comment of @Irfan Latif solved the problem. Going to Settings -> Apps -> Termux -> Permissions) and granting (i e. checking the box).